# Can I write a generic method signature that I could override in the inherited children?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, signature

I'm in a situation where I have a `Bag` that has a `AddSlot` method inside.
I have two types of bags, `ItemsBag` and `DCBag` (stands for draggable content)
`ItemsBag` is a 2D bag meaning it has rows and columns, `DCBag` is 1D, it has only one column but many rows (Which means I can consider it 2D as well).

Now the thing is, since the first bag deals with 2D indices, I would want `AddSlot` signature to be something like this:

```
public void AddSlot(int r, int c);
```

And the other bag's `AddSlot`:

```
public void AddSlot(int r);
```

How can I write a virtual/abstract signature of `AddSlot` in `Bag` such that when `ItemsBag` and `DCBag` inherit from `Bag` they can override the signature in the way I mentioned above?

As I said, I can consider the `DCBag` to be 2D as well, so that both it and `ItemsBag` have the same signature, but I really want to know if I could do this, it's very interesting.

I could get away using a variable number of arguments `params obejct[] args` but it would be nice to do it in a way that doesn't involve boxing/unboxing.

I could also make a `TwoDimBag` and `OneDimBag` make them both inherit from `Bag`, write the definitions of `AddSlot` in them the way I want to, and then make `ItemsBag` inherit `TwoDimBag` and `DCBag` inherit `OneDimBag`, but I'm not looking for work-arounds more than how to achieve what I'm asking for.

Again to recap one last time: how can I write a signature that I could override in the inheriting children? (that is, if I can and there is a way)

Thanks.

EDIT: (Extra Info)
The `Bag` has a lot of functionality in it. The difference between the two bags is that `ItemsBag` holds a 2d List of Slot (`List<List<Slot>>`), while `DCBag` has a 1d `List` of `Slot`. It's the `Slot` that holds an `Item`. - Items in `ItemsBag` could take more than one `Slot`, items in `DCBag` take only one.

Some of the things you can do in both bags: `AddSlot`, `FreeSlot`, `AddItem` (adding strategy differs, there are also extra adding methods in `ItemsBag`), in both the bags you could pickup an item with your mouse, swap items, sort items, both bags also receive notifications from slots to take necessary actions like `Notify_ClickedOnEmptySlot(Slot slot)`

Some of things you can only do in `ItemsBag`:
Combine items, adding a row of slots, adding a col of slots and rotate items.

Here's how the bags differ in terms of appearance, `ItemsBag` ([here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-RxdtzI6Hs) an old demo):

[image]

`DCBag`:

[image]

Comment: Well it's not the solution, but one detail : you can use `params int[] args`, no need to use `object[]`

Comment: I actually ended up doing this. It was the most affordable way, other solutions either provide more redundancy or complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object is a *bag of items*, then consider making the *item* type [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx).

I.e. you would have a generic `Bag<T>` class:

```
class Bag<T>
{
     private readonly List<T> _items = new List<T>();
     public void AddSlot(T item)
     {
         _items.Add(item);
     }
}
```

In that case, your item type can be anything:

```
class Item1D
{ 
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class Item2D
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

And providing that the "bag" functionality is the same for all items, you will instantiate different bags by passing the appropriate generic type:

```
var bag1D = new Bag<Item1D>();
var bag2D = new Bag<Item2D>();
```

Or, you could even pass a list of items as the generic parameter:

```
var bagOfSlots = new Bag<Slot>();
var bagOfListOfSlots = new Bag<List<Slot>>();
```

Check out the classes in the [`System.Collections.Generic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) namespace, that's the general idea. Also, whether you actually need to make it virtual depends on what the responsibility of the `Bag` class should be (check out the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). A rule of thumb in OOP is to keep classes' responsibilities as simple as possible (and a "bag" implies simply an unordered collection of items).

**[update]**

If the `DCBag` is more or less an `ItemBag` with a single column, then you can use the `new` keyword to change the signature of the method while still having access to the base method:

```
class ItemBag
{
    public virtual void AddSlot(int r, int c)
    {

    }
}

class DCBag : ItemBag
{
    public new void AddSlot(int r)
    {
        // we only have a single column
        base.AddSlot(r, 0);
    }
}
```

Note that this is not *overriding* the method, but instead creating a new method with the same name. In other words, you can call:

```
ItemBag itemBag = new ItemBag();
itemBag.AddSlot(3, 4);

DCBag dcBag = new DCBag();
dcBag.AddSlot(3);
```

But you cannot have dynamic dispatch (I presume you don't need it anyway in this case):

```
// if dcBag is of type ItemBag
ItemBag dcBag;

// ...and you instantiate it to a DCBag...
dcBag = new DCBag();

// ...you still end up with a virtual signature...
dcBag.AddSlot(3, 4);

// ...and the new method is inaccessible
dcBag.AddSlot(3); // <-- this will not compile
```

Comment: Actually the bag holds a `List` of `Slot`, this list could be 2D (List of List of Slot) or 1D. Then the `Slot` has an `Item` (`AddSlot` adds a `Slot` and not an `Item`)- Your solution is interesting, but you could you please update it correctly to include this information?

Comment: @VeXe: Can you clarify a bit how these two classes differ in functionality? I.e. what if you represented them as `Bag<Slot>` and `Bag<List<Slot>>`? Is your `Bag` more than a collection of items? What other methods does it have?

Comment: I've added some extra detail, I hope I answered you in a way, let me know if you need more.

Comment: @VeXe: So the `AddSlot` method adds a new empty slow at `(r, c)`. Do you actually ever add a single slot, or you always add the entire row or column?

Comment: I add an entire row/col by adding a number of slots that is equal to `nCols`/`nRows` :) - Most the times, the row/col is added last (I don't add in the middle of the bag or something, although the method allows me to do so should I want) - that is, I always add a row at the very bottom, and a col to the very right. If you're still curious, check out the demo I linked in the update to see this in action.

Comment: The `DCBag` doesn't have this functionality, there's no adding rows/cols. I just add a `Slot` to it, it gets added to the end of the scroll view.

Comment: @VeXe: Ok, so what I meant to say was: if you only need a `AddNewRow` and `AddNewCol` method in the `ItemsBag`, that would leave you with only the `AddNewRow` method for the `DCBag` (and it would add a row of length 1, i.e. with a single column). I.e. adding a `Slot` to a `DCBag` is basically adding a row of length 1. If the bag keeps track of its row count and col count, it should do the right thing in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can have specify this method in a base class and use an optional parameter.

```
public void AddSlot(int r, int c = 0)
{
}
```

Then, when you call it like this.

```
itemsBag.AddSlot(1, 1);
dcBag.AddSlot(1);
```

And since both types are 2D as you said, you can treat them the same way, can't you?

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment, define in your base class also

```
private abstract void AddSlotInternally(int r, int c);
```

where you will define a specific behaviour for your bags as they have to override this.

```
public void AddSlot(int r, int c = 0)
{
    AddSlotInternally(r, c);
}
```

I don't think that this solution is so bad, that other developers wouldn't underestand. Generics are sometimes more confusing than simple base method.

Comment: Thanks. That is correct, I can do that yes. But the thing is, in `ItemsBag` I'm using a `List` of `List` of `Slot` (2d List). In `DCBag` I just wanna use a `List` of `Slot` (1d List), I could use a 2d List, but it just seems redundant. In your solution I would end up with an extra parameter what I won't use all the time.

Comment: And anybody using this class would see that the method has two arguments. But in one case, the second argument is useless... When you go to this kind of things, I would say that your inheritance strategy is far from clear.